# Running mvn liquibase:updateSQL on a specific changeSet

Tags: maven, liquibase

Somebody who's a more seasoned maven user can probably help me out here:

how do I pass in "optional parameters" to liquibase when running it as a maven goal?

I want to pass in "changesToApply", see http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven_updatesql

But what's the syntax? 
Something like this, but not quite:

```
mvn liquibase:updateSQL -DchangesToApply=2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

```
mvn liquibase:updateSQL -Dliquibase.changesToApply=2
```

Long answer

Go to the parameter you're interested and look for it's expression. 
http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven_updatesql#changesToApply

Look for

```
changesToApply:

The number of changes to apply to the database. By default this value is 0, which will result in all changes (not already applied to the database) being applied.
Type: int
Required: No
Expression: ${liquibase.changesToApply}
Default: 0
```

From this, you can see the expression is `${liquibase.changesToApply}`

```
Expression: ${liquibase.changesToApply}
```

That's what you should use

Comment: Aha! I was pretty close then, just missing a "liquibase.". Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 1):

From [Maven Liquibase plugin manual](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven)

> All the parameters for executing the Maven Liquibase plugin can also
>   be specified in `<configuration>` section of the plugin. Below is an example of this:

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquiabse/business_table.xml</changeLogFile>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@tf-appserv-linux:1521:xe</url>
        <username>liquibaseTest</username>
        <password>pass</password>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:
mvn liquibase:updateSQL -P mysql -DskipTests -Dliquibase.changeLogFile=create.xml

where my change log file is "create.xml"
and "mysql" a pre-configured profile to populate my database properties file.

**make sure** though that the change log file is not hard coded in the liquibase.properties file
and **make sure** that you rebuild the module because the maven goal will use the liquibase.properties in the target/classes directory of the module

Answer (score 1):

For the version 3.5.5   should go outside `<executions>` like below:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/business_table.xml</changeLogFile>
          <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@tf-appserv-linux:1521:xe</url>
          <username>liquibaseTest</username>
          <password>pass</password>
        </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>update</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```